# Binding AngularJS directive to element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, raphael

I have created `SVG` image on dom using `javaScript`. Now I want to bind directive on these images.I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me to find the solution?
 Thank You.
I am writing here My code:
I want to add this forImage Directive to image element. In simple words I just want to know that If I create an element on `DOM` using `javaScript`, than how to `bind` event on it using `Angular directive.`
**Update**:I found that $compile is used to dynamically add directive. Is there any way to compile DOM from cntroller?

```
//HTML
<body ng-controller= "Ctrl" >
        <div class="row">
            <div id="editor"></div>
            </div>
</body>

//My controller
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {

var paper = Raphael("editor", 635,500);// Raphael element(it creates SVG tag) to draw image.
var image = paper.image(img.src, 200, 200,300,400);// Image drawn on the SVG.
})
//My directive
app.directive('forImage', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'CA',
        link: function (scope,elem,attr) {
            elem.bind('mousedown', function (e) {    // Mousedown event to be bind on image
             console.log("Image binding");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle of what you have tried

Comment: I want to add forImage directive to Image element.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then try this: <img src="YourImage.png" for-image>

Comment: No. Actually there is no any img tag in Html.

Comment: I am updating my code. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think this is finally the solution. Take a look at the fiddle. 
I added a red rectangle, so that you can see, your directive only triggers on the image. 
I use $compile to make the added directive (`setAttribute()`) work.

```
app.directive('raphaelDir', function($compile) {
      return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<div id="editor"></div>',
      link : function(scope,element, attrs) {
      var paper = Raphael("editor", 500,500);
      var image = paper.image(
      "http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg",
       20,30,100,100);
      image.node.setAttribute('for-image', '');
      $compile(element)(scope);
  },
 };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnfve2tx/5/

Comment: No, It is not working. I tried it before asking here.

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? Doesn't the image tag contains the attribute `forImage`? Or does your function not work? The added attribute works fine for me.

Comment: Image tag contains forImage, but event is not binding on image.

Comment: See the link I attached. You surely need to use $compile.

Comment: do i need to do like this,  $compile(image)($scope);? Is it correct?

Comment: To see how you use $compile correctly see: [Angular Compile How it works, how to use](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html).
I was just thinking why you don't append the Raphael object to the DOM in your directive?

Comment: Do i need to compile Image tag only or all DOM?

Comment: why you don't append the Raphael object to the DOM in your directive? Can you explain this? or please provide a fiddle link with example.

Comment: I added a quick and dirty solution. Take a look, maybe that's what you need. Just let me know. I did not need to use the compile statement. However, I'm not sure if this goes along well with the Angular guidelines.

Comment: Your approach is excellent but the problem is still there. I want to bind mousedown event directive only with the Images. In this case mousedown event fires on all div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66964/discussion-between-ved-and-rodrigodela).

Comment: Take a look at the provided solution. Leveraging $compile and adding the directive dynamically works fine. Hope that is what you need.

Comment: That is where I am facing problem. NOt able to find the way, how to use $compile here.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Take a look at it. It shows how to use $compile for your problem.

Comment: Yup, working.. your efforts need answer to be selected my me. thank You.

Comment: I am thinking, why I cant use $compile in controller. $compile(image)($scope) not working.

Comment: Why would you? $compile only works on directives. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive $compile is actually what makes directives work, it would make no sense to use it in a controller.

Comment: That is what I am thinking too. Actually I can't use directive in my case. There is some reasons. So I am thinking how to make add directive and compile it.